# Restore changes that were overwritten by git pull

Tags: git, git-reflog

I'm having an issue with git where I can't retrieve changes that were overridden by `git pull`.

I had started work on a project without a GitHub repository, which I then later made. I forked the repository when it was made, which included a `README` file.

I added the files, locally, that I wanted to push the the repository using `git add`, but then realized I should pull the `README` first from the GitHub repository.

After pulling, I attempted to push my changes, but instead got the message `Everything up-to-date`.

I used the `ls` command to find that the files added with `git add` were removed and replaced by the `README.md`.

These are the commands I performed:
[image: commands]

Using `git log` just showed the commits made by the other person working on the project on the `README`. I guess that was expected, considering I had made no commits.

Using `git reflog` showed that I made one pull, (`HEAD@{0}`) but using `git reset --hard HEAD@{0}` didn't seem to do anything. I also attempted `git reset --hard HEAD@{"20 minutes ago"}` but only got warnings that the log only went back to my first pull.

**Is there a way to restore uncommitted changes overwritten by a pull?**

**EDIT**:

I apologize for not doing my homework, I noticed a question on the sidebar that this question is a duplicate of: [Git pull deleted uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268940/git-pull-deleted-uncommitted-changes?rq=1)

I'm going to be using the lost-found (`cd .git/lost-found/other`) to attempt to restore my changes.

**Is there an easier way to restore the changes than lost-found**, I guess is the new question. If not, I'll answer myself with the method I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the question, a solution I used to restore my changes was using git's lost-found.

I used `cd .git/lost-found/other/` to take myself to the lost and found where the files were.

I opened each file in the directory to see what it's name was, then moved it to the correct directory with the correct name.

I used `git add` to add the changes and commit them, so now I won't lose them again.