# Pushing changes to Git branch, but told to pull first, but a pull loses my own work

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Four of our members are working on a Git branch called "Dev". I have completed some of my work and when trying to push it, it gives me an error because someone has already made a commit/push to "dev". It says to pull first and push, but when I did pull my modified data was lost. However, when I switched to using master branch, I recovered.

How I am going to push my changes to "dev" without removing changes from other developers as well?

Comment: Do a merge. Git's merging capabilities seem poor though so prepare yourself for conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't lose your work *if you add it*  to the index first, and commit it, before the `git pull`.

`git pull` will [fetch and merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/6309) the [upstream `dev` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) or the [upstream repo '`origin`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) to your current branch '`dev`'.

But if you didn't commit, then your changes would be "lost".

Except you can still find them with a:

```
git fsck --lost-found  => give a SHA1
git cat-file -p SHA1 => see the content of your lost work
```

See "[Git pull deleted uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270385/6309)" for more.

Comment: Hi VonC, can you please tell me how I am gonna add it to the index first? I am new to Git.

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra by using the [command `git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), as described in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra note that the index is a very important notion to understand: see my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/6309

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash` in this scenario.

```
#git stash
#git pull
#git stash pop / git stash apply <stash id> (you can look up the stash id with `git stash list`)
```

In generally, git will auto merge the code if you don't modify the same line. Otherwise you should merge the code manually somtimes, then you can commit and push your code