# how to fix git checkout command by mistake?

Tags: git, github

Hi guys I am new to git .

1. I created a branch and commited my files on it .
2. then created another branch (this one is the one i want to push) .
3. pulled the first branch to the new branch .
4. mistakenly did

   ```
   git checkout
   ```

instead of

```
git checkout "file"
```

Now when I type `git status` i get a message

> nothing to commit

What can I do?

Comment: `git checkout` without any further arguments is a "glorified no-op", as the docs put it (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout). So this operation did not do anything. Whatever is wrong with your tree, it is caused by something else.

Comment: what about git checkout . ? @letitbee

Comment: Yep, that's bad. This will kill all your changes.

Comment: And no way to undo it. Git cannot help you if you have not commited your code in any way, or at least stashed it. But the good news is if you have commited, there is almost always a way to get it back.

Comment: well I commited the files on another branch , then switched to a new branch and pulled that branch ,, so the changes are there one that branch but i checked them on this one i am on now ...so what i want is to have them on my current branch

Comment: What do you mean by "pushed the first branch to the new branch"

Comment: sorry I pulled it .. i did git pull origin firstBranch

Comment: you describe the process you have done, can you add the command? I can't understand how you can pull a local branch.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond i just did in my previous comment ... "git pull branch"

Comment: I mean the whole process. I can see two options, you are missunderstanding how commit and push works, or i am missing somethink you have done.
As far as i can see you did not pushed anithing, but you are trying to pull a branch that have never been pushed, and this is not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84302/discussion-between-anthony-raymond-and-sisimh).

Answer (score 1):

You can revert to previous commit, ignoring any changes: `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Where *HEAD* is the last commit in your current branch.

If you want to get remote *gh-pages* branch: `git reset --hard origin/gh-pages`.

Comment: i dont have a commit on my current branch , I pulled another branch then did checkout . by mistake , what can I do now ?

Comment: if "there is nothing to commit" it is already at the previous commit state

Comment: but i pulled another branch and I want that branch's files to commit them on this branch , so now after the checkout i dont see the files anymore @AnthonyRaymond ,, so what can I do now ?

Comment: Can you please add to you post the complete list of operation you have done?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missunderstanding `commit` and `push`.

A `commit` is like a pictures you are shooting with a camera. (you specifie what elements you want to add to this pictures with `add`).

When you have taken this pictures, it will stay in you album (where nobody execpt you can see it).

How to :
`git add <path_to_file_1>`
`git add <path_to_file_2>`
`git commit -m "my commit message to describe what i had done"`

A `push` is use to send you album to a repository.

How to :
`git push <repo_name> <branchName>`

When code is into a distant repository, it can be pulled to be merged with your code.

How to :
`git pull <repo_name> <repoBranch>`

What have you done.

As far as i understand, you have done the following sequence.

```
git branch my_first_branch
git checkout my_first_branch
..... working on your branch, modifying files .....
git add < all my files>
git commit -m "Hey this is my first commit"

git branch my_second_branch
# At this point, since you created your second_branch from first_branch, second branch contains all modifications made to first_branch, there are both the same.

git pull origin first_branch
# This should have failed unless you have push ????

git checkout
# this should have done nothing
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I have done , but my case is git checkout . :(

Comment: `git checkout` without arguments should do nothing, have you lost the changes you have made ?

Comment: yes after I pulled the first branch i had many changes , then now i lost them all

Comment: So after creating the branch, you have done some modifications, then pull, without commit?

Comment: yes exactly . I want to push on this new branch it is connected to my task while that first one is not

Comment: Ok, i think i found what you need, take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268940/git-pull-deleted-uncommitted-changes

I have to go i'll be back tomorrow, hope this will help you

Comment: what are my steps now can you tell ?