# How to restore files deleted by git pull rebase

Tags: git, unix

something quite tragic happened to all my files in my project after I did a `git pull rebase`. I tried to follow the tips in this thread:

[Git pull deleted uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268940/git-pull-deleted-uncommitted-changes)

especially the second solution and I have been trying this:

```
grep -rin string_in_missing_file .git/
```

I see results in the terminal like this:

```
.git//rebase-apply/0002:9609:+const ExplainSection = styled.div`
.git//rebase-apply/0002:9614:+const SectionNumber = styled.div`
.git//rebase-apply/0002:9621:+const SectionImage = styled.div`
.git//rebase-apply/0002:9626:+const SectionText = styled.div`
```

It seems that info about my files are still floating around somewhere, but I have no idea how to restore them, or if it is even still possible.

Please help me out here :(

Answer (score 0):

Check `git reflog` so you can see where HEAD has been recently. That way you could go as far as to get the branch reset to where it was before. As long as those files where committed, you won't lose them that easily.

Comment: Yup, I have tried that already. It only goes as far as to:

7ee637c (HEAD, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: pull --rebase origin master: checkout 7ee637cae5081160e910bd060b24c923b54d8da3

I can't seem to restore anything before that